# Is it possible to add a column with unique constraint in one go?

Tags: postgresql, ddl, postgresql-11

I want to add an `email` column to an existing table with the `UNIQUE` constraint. Is it possible to do this with one statement?

When I try:

```
ALTER TABLE "Corporates"
ADD COLUMN "email" varchar(100) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT "Corporates_email_key" UNIQUE ("email")
```

the query fails with the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 3:     CONSTRAINT "Corporates_email_key" UNIQUE ("email")
                                                     ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 120
```

OTOH I could run the following two statements individually:

```
ALTER TABLE "Corporates"
ADD COLUMN "email" varchar(100) NOT NULL
```

and then:

```
ALTER TABLE "Corporates"
ADD CONSTRAINT "Corporates_email_key" UNIQUE ("email")
```

and it worked.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a second `ADD` option:

```
ALTER TABLE corporates
  ADD COLUMN email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT corporates_email_key UNIQUE (email);
```

Comment: Turns out the double quotes were necessary, but otherwise the query worked: needed the `ADD` and the comma. Thanks!

Comment: I know the double quotes were necessary because you already messed up and used them when creating the table. If you can, try to re-created your table(s) without double quotes.

Comment: The original tables were created by Sequelize, & looks like it _always_ uses double quotes... this was a special case where the original setup was done by migrations, but for a specific reason the change had to be made by hand.